# Adding csv with lesser column than schema to BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, database-design, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with 100 columns. Now I want to append more rows to it via Transfer but the new CSV has only 99 columns. How should I proceed with this?

I tried creating a schema and adding that column as NULLABLE but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming your CSV file is stored in GCS Bucket and trying to use BQ Data Transfer service to load data periodically by scheduling it.

You can not directly Load/Append data into BQ Table due to schema mismatch.

But as an alternative, create a Staging table named `staging_table_csv` with 99 columns and Schedule a Data transfer service to load CSV to this table on Overwrite mode.

Now write a query to Append the contents of this staging table `staging_table_csv` to the target BQ table.

Query might look like this:

```
#standardSQL
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.target_table`
SELECT
  *,
  <DEFAULT_VALUE> AS COL100
FROM 
  `project.dataset.staging_table_csv`
```

Now schedule this query to run after the staging table is loaded
[image]

Make sure to keep a buffer between the Staging table load and the Target Table load. You can perform trials to find a suitable buffer.

For eg: If Transfer is scheduled at 12:00, Schedule Target Table load Query t 12:05 or 12:10

> Note: Creating an extra Staging table would incur storage costs but
> since it is overwritten for each load, historical data cost is not
> incurred